# Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal/Observable'

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, token

I want to use JwtHelperService module in my service but I got below error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwt.interceptor.d.ts(3,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal/Observable'.
```

I have isAuthenticated function in my service.

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable()
export class MembershipService{
    constructor(private http: Http,
       private mainService: MainService,
       public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService){}

    public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('loggedToken');
        // Check whether the token is expired and return
        // true or false
        return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);

    }
}
```

Also my angular version is 5.0

I appreciate any help

Comment: Are you using version 2 of angular2-jwt?

Comment: I installed npm install --save @auth0/angular-jwt

Comment: and which version of angular?

Comment: version of angular is 5.0

Comment: you are using wrong version of it, try [angular2-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt) that is compatible with Angular v5 and RxJS v5.

Comment: Thanks fateme, It's worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it sounds like this is a mismatch of RxJS versions. angular2-jwt v2 targets RxJS v6. For use with Angular v5 and RxJS v5, you should use angular2-jwt v1.

Comment: I installed npm install --save @auth0/angular-jwt

Comment: use 
npm install --save angular2-jwt